# Function from the template code is not called

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In code I have call, for example addComment, why after pasted from HTML do directiv template she didn't work? What should I do.

And second question is what differences is between

```
modal-window-card card="card"
```

and

```
modal-window-card="card"
```

Because I saw that probably I have only assigned variable `card.name` and in first example I have whole object but why?

#### HTML:

```
 <div modal-window-card card="card"></div>
```

#### Directiv:

```
App.directive('modalWindowCard', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            card: "=", 
        },
        template: `
        <div id="{{$parent.$parent.$index}}/{{$parent.$index}}" class="modalDialog">
            <div>
                <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
                <div>
                    <div class="windows-title">
                        <span class="header">{{ card.name }} </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="window-header">
                        <p class="quiet-header">W liscie {{ item.list }}</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="windows-description">
                        <span class="loud-header">Dodaj komentarz:</span>
                        <form ng-submit="addComment($parent.$index, $index, commentCard)">
                            <input id="text2" ng-model="commentCard" cols="30" rows="5"> 
                          </form>
                            <button ng-click="addComment($parent.$index, $index, commentCard)" style="margin-top:5px;">Zapisz</button>
                       </div>

                        <div class="window-activity">
                            <span class="loud-header">Aktywnosc</span>
                            <span class="quiet-header" style="float: right; margin-right: 310px;">Pokaz Szczególy</span>
                            <div class="window-comments">
                                <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #E2E4E6; margin-top: 5px;" ng-repeat="comment in card.comments">
                                    <span class="name-header">{{ comment.author }}</span>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>`
   }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use @ instead of using =

```
scope: {
        card: "@", 
    }
```

in div element

```
<div modal-window-card card="card value is here"></div>
```

You are calling a directive "modalWindowCard" using **modal-window-card** and you are passing the attribute named "card" to the directive's isolate scope property.

in this case

```
<div modal-window-card="card value is here"></div>
```

Angularjs tries to find a directive but it can't parse this '='. The name '**card**' in modal-window-**card**="card value is here" is NOT an attribute which you can send it to the directive.

I have modified your code please check [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/FwKVcks25YgKfGRi4lS3?p=preview)

Comment: If I have any function that only uses the directive then take it from the controller and give it to the directive always?